# How do I get the percentage of upvotes using the Reddit API in java

Tags: java, api, percentage, reddit, vote

I'm trying to get the percentage of upvotes for a given reddit post, or even the number of downvotes.  I'm getting the JSON and parsing through it.  I notice that the upvotes are readily available but not sure how accurate it is since it matches the score.  I think getting the percentage is possible since reddit apps are able to display this information.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a [tour].

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.  It turns out that the data for upvote percentage is located inside the post's JSON and not available in the feed's JSON.  Once you're inside the post's JSON, the percentage, it can be found under "upvote_ratio"